# Prove that there is prime number and natural so $n\times q$ digits are $1$.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, prime-numbers, prime-factorization

I need your helping to prove that there is a prime number $ 2\lt n\in \mathbb N$ and $ 5\neq q\in \mathbb N$ so that the digits of $n\times q$ are only $1$.

for example:if $n=3$ then $3\times 37=111$

if $n=7$ then $7\times 15873=111111 $

also if $2<n\in \mathbb N$ is odd and not divisible by $5$,  $q\in \mathbb N$* , so $n\times q$ are only $1$ digits.

Comment: Is this saying that for any prime number $q$ apart from $5$ the is some $n$ (which may or may not be prime) such that $nq$ is a sequence of $1$s, i.e. of the form $\dfrac{10^d-1}{9}$ for some $d$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an alternative solution to the problem

> Given a prime number $p \notin \lbrace 2, 5 \rbrace$, there exists a
>   mutliple $np$ which consists only of ones.

Consider the first $p+1$ postive integers which consit only of ones, i.e. the integers

$$1,11,
111,\dots, \underbrace{1 \cdots 1}_{p+1}
$$

There are two among these, whose remainders upon divison by $p$ are equal (since there are only $p$ remainders, but $p+1$ numbers). Hence the diffrence of two such numbers is divisible by $p$ and looks like
$$11\cdots 1100\cdots 00 = (11\cdots 11) \cdot 10^k$$
where $k$ is the number of zeros. As $p$ is not equal to 2 or 5, $p$ does not divide $10^k$. But $p$ divides the product $(11\cdots 11) \cdot 10^k$, hence $p$ divides $11\cdots11$.

Comment: @nitramellots but why does the diffrence is divisible by p

Comment: If integers a and b have the same reamainder upon divison by p, say r, we can write them as a = kp+r, b = mp+r. Hence a-b = p(k-m) is a multiple of p.

Comment: !
Great thank you so much,
what about the second part? if $2<n\in N$ is odd and not divided by 5, i need to prove that there is  $q\in N$* , so $n*q$ are only 1 digits.

Comment: You can use exactly the same proof with p replaced by q. What matters is that q cannot divide 10^k if it q is odd and no multiple of 5, so q has to divide the 1...1-part. (This follows from the uniqueness of prime factorizations.)

Comment: @nitramellots Great! and last question, what another number(which isnt 1 ) can do the same trick with digits? and why?

Answer (score 1):

$\underbrace{11\cdots11}_{( d\text{ digits})}=\dfrac{10^d-1}9$ where $d$ is any positive integer

We need $\dfrac{10^d-1}9\equiv0\pmod p$

For $p=3, 111=3\cdot37$

For $p>5,\dfrac{10^d-1}9\equiv0\pmod p\iff10^d\equiv1\pmod p$

The sufficient condition is $d$ is divisible by $(p-1)$ (from Fermat's Little Theorem)

Comment: Is this $(p-1)|d$ and the multipliers are $\dfrac{10^{k(p-1)}-1}{9p}$ for positive integers $k$?

Comment: @Henry, Exactly.

Comment: @labbhattacharjee what about the second part? if n is odd and not divided by 5 can you show that still there is q∈N so the digits of n*q are only 1 digits.

Comment: @user152711, $$\dfrac{10^{k(p-1)}-1}p$$ is always a natural number

Comment: @labbhattacharjee but how does it work with the odd and not divided by 5?  2<n∈N and odd, and not divided by 5,  q∈N* , so n*q are only 1 digits.

Comment: @user152711, As $$(10^{k(p-1)}-1,10)=1\implies(10^{k(p-1)}-1,2)=(10^{k(p-1)}-1,5)=1$$

Comment: @labbhattacharjee im sorry but i dont really understand everything,
why do we need to mod p so it will be 0? (can you please explain it?), and thats enough to prove that there is a prime number that do so?
also i have'nt learned fermat little theorem,  i dont really get the p-1 thing you wrote in...