# Find all $a$, so $q$ prime number which ,$q\times n= aaaaaaa$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, prime-numbers, prime-factorization

I need your helping to find all the $a$ numbers,which follow the next rules:

there is prime number $ 2\lt n\in \mathbb N$ and $ 5\neq q\in \mathbb N$ so that the digits of $n\times q$ are only $a$.

for example:$n\times q=aaaaaaa$

if $n=7$,$a=1, 7\times 15873=111111$

and also if $2\lt n\in \mathbb N$ is odd and not divided by $5$,  $q\in \mathbb N$* , so $n\times q$ are only $a$ digits.

I need to find all the $a$ numbers which follow this rule , except $1$.

Comment: Hint: Solving this problem for $a=1$ is sufficient because you can calculate the values for $a$ by replacing $q$ by $qa$

Comment: @StellaBiderman well i dont need to solve this, its true for a=1 , but i need to find other 'a' digits which work with it also.

Comment: For people who are interested but haven't read the other post: related to this post (same author): http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1630291/proof-that-there-is-prime-number-and-natural-so-nq-digits-are-1

Comment: Have you tried $7\cdot 31\,746$?

Comment: You confuse $n,a,q$ in your example and the multipliction is not correct.  It should be $7 * 15873=111111$, so is $q=15873$?  You can just take the $q$ from your other post and multiply it by $2,3,4,\dots 9$ to get an answer.  If all you want are $a$'s, we can find an example for each digit.  Please think more clearly about your question.

Comment: @RossMillikan , so your saying that I can find proof for any digit i choose between 1 to 9? , i can find n and q so, $n*q=999999$, and for any number id choose

Comment: Which one is prime?  n, q or both?

Comment: @fleablood only n

Comment: 15873 is not prime.  So it seems you just need prime $\times$ number = aaaaa.  The values of a are not relevent as aaaaa = a$\times$1111111, so if prime $\times$ number =  aaaaa it is sufficient to show prime $\times (a $\times$ (number/a) = 1111111.  (a must divide prime $\times$ number but prime is prime so either a divides number or a = prime [in which case number = 111111]).

Comment: Then, as every one else is pointing out, the value of a is irrelevant and trivial.  $n \times q = aaaaaa \iff $ $n \times q/a = 111111$ or $n = a; q = 111111$ and a can be any possible digit (except 0).

Comment: And indeed, any number $m = 1 \cdots 1$ can be factored into primes as $p_1 \cdots p_r$, yielding factorizations of the desired form with $n = p_i$, $q = \frac{m}{p_i}$, and we need only exclude the examples with $n = 2$ and $q = 5$. A little more work shows that we can always find a factorization of $a \cdots a$ (when there is more than $1$ digit in the number) that satisfies the given conditions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*All* numbers from $a = 1...9$ follow the rule.

$7\times 15873=111111$

$7\times 2*15873=222222$

$7\times 3*15873=333333$

$7\times 4*15873=444444$

.....

Comment: @user152712 this is what I meant.

Comment: Well, no offense, but it *was* pretty obvious...